# Holding right mouse button doesn't work in game but works otherwise

Tags: windows-10, mouse

In Witcher 3, holding the right mouse button intermittently (but mostly) doesn't work, making the game unplayable.  This feature works otherwise in Windows 10.  The mouse is just a basic Gear Head wired USB mouse.  There doesn't seem to be a driver other than the standard Windows HID driver, nor is there extra mouse software.  Rebooting the machine doesn't help.

How should I further troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Have you tried another mouse? Does your current mouse work correctly on another system with Witcher 3 installed?

Comment: @LPChip A different mouse (a Logitech wireless one) doesn't exhibit this problem.  I don't currently have a great way to install Witcher 3 on a different PC to try that fix out.

Comment: So its most likely an issue with the mouse then. Consider replacing the mouse, or see if the manufacturer website offers drivers and install those.